# Programmatically restoring ms-sql system database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

While there are plenty of questions and answers for dealing with programmatic backup restoration from the perspective of restoring a "normal" database, doing so for a system database like `[master]`, `[msdb]`, or `[model]` I run into many varied issues. I wonder if anyone has something to contribute, especially for `[master]`, but all of these appear to cause issues. For now, I've started ms-sql in single-user mode (the entire service) to restore the master database with the T3608 flag, but the moment I try to run a `RESTORE DATABASE` query on it this breaks my connection with a broken pipe message. Inspecting the services console `services.msc` reveals that the database service is no longer running.

In other words, running this query appears to crash sql-server with no useful message result.

Let's look at some example code. Query generation code looks like:

```
string query = "RESTORE DATABASE @dbName FROM DISK " + 
    "= @backupPath WITH FILE = @fileID, REPLACE, ";
if (dataFileName != "") {
    query += "MOVE @dataFileName TO @dataFileLocation, ";
}
if (logFileName != "") {
    query += "MOVE @logFileName TO @logFileLocation, ";
}
query += "STATS=1";
SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbName", databaseName);
cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@backupPath", filePath);
cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileID", fileIndex);
if (dataFileName != "") {
    cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataFileName", dataFileName);
    cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataFileLocation", mdfPath);
}
if (logFileName != "") {
    cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logFileName", logFileName);
    cmdData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logFileLocation", ldfPath);
}
cmdData.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So it's pretty much a simplest possible example. FileIndex is an integer containing the backup file index, all the other variables that aren't initialized here are strings containing the various paths and names.  Note that manually executing this kind of query produces the expected result (a backup file is restored).

The event log makes things even weirder. I observe this message:

> Snapshot isolation or read committed snapshot is not available in database 'master' because SQL Server was started with one or more undocumented trace flags that prevent enabling database for versioning. Transaction started with snapshot isolation will fail and a query running under read committed snapshot will succeed but will resort back to lock based read committed.

where it presumably complains about T3608. The event log also contains messages about "succesful restoration", but inspecting the contents of the `DATA` folder reveals that my program does not in fact put back database files that I manually delete, but appears to do nothing instead?

I am very confused by sql server's strange behaviour at this point. Can anyone shed some light on how this could possibly happen?

**Edit:**

Some more digging and experimentation with changing the process reveals that the msdb and model databases are in fact also needed or SQL server will not start up properly. Hence all three need to be present to be able to restore them, and you can only restore the three, what I will now call *special databases* in special, convoluted, specific ways that are different for each and every one of them.

Exactly what and how I am not sure about yet. The internet contains a bunch of conflicting advice, and not one documented procedure works straight up.

I've discovered that ms-sql keeps a special folder "Template Data". In here there are a bunch of templates for the special databases. I can copy these templates into the real DATA folder to have a running sql-server to restore the backed up special databases from.

But: doing this: during the restore of the non-master specials (msdb and model) the server still terminates itself. It's likely that actually there isn't anything being restored.

Further inspecting log files reveals these two interesting errors though:

> During redoing of a logged operation in database 'model', an error occurred at log record ID (32:151:1). Typically, the specific failure is previously logged as an error in the Windows Event Log service. Restore the database from a full backup, or repair the database.
>
> The operating system returned error 5(Access Denied.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0000000000000000 in file 'E:\backupdb\MSSQL12.TBUINST\MSSQL\Template Data\modellog.ldf'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Why is it now trying to read something in "Template data"? Is it because the template system db or msdb db or model db contains refs to the hard-coded path(s) of the template model/msdb/etc db **inside of itself** and I have to issue move commands? When/How in the restore process do I issue these?

I also realized this: Presuming that I restore the 'master' database first, and that **it** contains the paths to the other special databases, why is SQL server now searching in the template data folder? It does, after all, restart when restoring the master database, so the paths in there should now be the defaults. Not to mention that, in every single restore operation, I explicity specify where **both** the `.bak` file and the new `.ldf` and `.mdf` files are to be located? This makes zero sense.

Comment: Only and admin can restore a backup.  Permissions change and the admin has to change permission before normal users can access the database.  Normal users can deattach and attach a database.

Comment: @jdweng User permissions are not an issue: this program is being launched as an administrator, so it can start/stop the sql server however many times it takes to do all the backup restores with various config flags. In addition, it checks beforehand whether it has admin rights on the SQL server as well. If it doesn't the user is asked to provide the SA password every time it reconnects to the database.

Comment: We found when any user Archives a database the Windows permissions of the file  becomes read only.  The when a restore get done only an admin can read the database.  A normal user cannot remove the read only while an admin can change the permissions so everybody can read.  What made the issue worse was the admin for the SQL Database was different from the Windows Admin.

Comment: Have you tried restoring from the same backup file via a manual process? Perhaps the file is corrupt.

Comment: 1. Does it fail in the same way if you manually run the commands (eg. via SSMS)? 2. What trace flags are being used?

Comment: oops, I see you mentioned 3608: whty are you running with this trace flag? From the description (and [others](https://sqlmaestros.com/sql-server-trace-flag-3608-might-encounter/)) this is likely to mess with many "normal" operations.

Comment: Flag 3608 is a necessary evil: what it does is not try to automatically load databases, except the master. I'm restoring a backup: these other databases may be missing or corrupt.

Comment: @aphid, SQL Server will just mark user databases as suspect if the files are missing or corrupt. You can still start SQL Server restore master without the `3608` trace flag, restore master, restart SQL Server, and finally restore user databases as needed.

Comment: No I can't. Just no. FCB: Open failed: Could not open file "(dbpath)\model.mdf". 
And then model.ldf. And then msdb.mdf. And then msdb.ldf... and then the files for the actual database. At this point i'm not really restoring anything am I? I'm supposed to be able to grab these files from the .bak files, not magically have them! The point is that of course, after restoring master, the db engine thinks that the other databases are there already.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server automatically stops when the master database restore completes. You'll need to handle the resultant connection error in your code, restart SQL Server, and then continue restoring the other system databases.

Comment: While I can handle the connection error and reconnect, and assumed this would be enough to fix my problem, upon closer inspection, it did not. The database does not restore. I test by renaming my .mdf and .ldf files and they are not recreated by the command. What is missing?

Comment: You can't start SQL Server without master database files so I don't understand how you were able to start the engine before the restore test after renaming the files. Note that the SQL Server uses the master database files `-d` and `-l` startup parameters.